# How do i Use SQL CMD and output a new file everytime a script is run in sql server?

Tags: cmd, sqlcmd

I have a script like below i put in a Job and it runs an outputs a file.

```
sqlcmd -E -i t:\export\test.sql -o t:\export\MyReport.txt
```

When i run this, it works well and outputs a file to the location specified.

What i am looking to do is, is there a way i can add to the code so that anytime this script runs, it will create a new file and not remove the old file the previous run generated? Basically if the job runs 10 times, i have 10 different files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some time added to your file name.

```sh
sqlcmd -E -i t:\export\test.sql -o t:\export\MyReport-%DATE%.txt
```

Comment: File paths should be quoted just in case there is a SPACE or other special character in them `sqlcmd -E -i "t:\export\test.sql" -o "t:\export\MyReport-%DATE%.txt"`,

Comment: @Justinas Used this and the output file name is MyReport-%DATE%.txt. And when it runs again, the new file replaces the old file which is something i am also looking to avoid. Please advise.

Comment: @lit i tried even with that and same results.

Comment: @analain29 Through where you are running your command? Maybe for some reason it's not expanding `%DATE%`? Write batch file where you pre-calculate output file name with randomness and then execute command

Comment: @analain29, if the DATE has not changed, it will be the same. (Does that qualify as profound?) You will need to replace characters, such as COLON, in the time which are invalid in a directory path and file name.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to all this so i do not quite understand the things you all have mentioned. Is  there a blog or something i can take a look at to see. I am running this command as a Job in SQL server. I would have thought it will create a new file with the file name having the date instead of having MyOutput-%DATE%.

Comment: @analain29 Just use google. E.g. https://sqlandme.com/tag/append-date-time-to-filename/